# Can choropleth graph of Plotly Express in Python accept colors in CSS format?

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I am making a choropleth graph on Plotly Express in Python to map the Government Respond on COVID-19; particularly in Africa.

The data source can be found [here](https://www.bsg.ox.ac.uk/research/research-projects/coronavirus-government-response-tracker#data).
It is an Oxford University dataset on Government Respond Tracker.

The example of the data source content (**for your convenience**):

```
CountryName|CountryCode|Date     |...|EconomicSupportIndexForDisplay
Algeria    | DZA       |20200101 |...| 0
Algeria    | DZA       |20200102 |...| 0
.........................................
Algeria    | DZA       |20200724 |...| 50
.........................................
```

In actuality, there are 42 columns with 30,000+ rows; where these rows are updated daily. 
However, not all of the countries are equally up to date (source Oxford GitHub [page](https://github.com/OxCGRT/covid-policy-tracker))

In my case, I have already build a database from it in PostgreSQL. 
This is my code so far;

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

''' PostgreSQL Variables '''
# PostgreSQL Login Variables (edited out)

''' PostgreSQL Connection '''
# PostgreSQL DB Connection code (edited out)

African_Query = pd.read_sql_query(
'''
# SQL Query to pull all African countries from the DB (e.g. 'Algeria, 'Angola', 'Benin', 'etc')
''', conn)
# except ('Comoros', 'Equatorial Guinea', 'Guinea Bissau', and 'Sao Tome and Principe')
# those countries were not exist in the datasource

African = pd.DataFrame(African_Query,
                       columns=['all column names from the datasource'])

''' Plotly graph '''
# Government Respond - School Closing
african_figure1 = px.choropleth(African,
                                locations="countrycode",
                                color="c1_school_closing",
                                color_continuous_scale="Blues",
                                range_color=[0, 3],
                                hover_data={"c1_school_closing": False,
                                            "countrycode": False,
                                            "countryname": False},
                                hover_name="countryname",
                                labels={"c1_school_closing": "SCALE"})

african_figure1.update_layout(geo_scope='africa',
                              title_text="Government Respond - SCHOOL CLOSING")

african_figure1.show()
```

The map is successfully created. Now I wanted to do the following things;

- I wanted to change the color that I used.
  From initially using the in-built color picker in Plotly to one of the CSS style color.
  For instance into the (#4c5c73)

***edit**: I have been trying to modify the value in the `'color_continuous_scale="some_color_value"'`, to no avail.
Or was I wrong to edit this?

Many thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi @aldy_abe, please do not ask multiple questions in the same post. It will be great if you could have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hi @rpanai many thanks for this!
I will update my question now.

edit: I have edited the question and I hope now it meets to the standard!

Comment: Hi @aldy_abe, here will be great to have a sample of your data rather than the query. It will be better if you delete all the `PostgreSQL` part.

Comment: Hi @rpanai, ok. I will edit it now.
Thank you for your input!

Comment: It seems that I cannot edit my previous comment above. 
Anyway, I have shortened the question and added some example of the data source content @rpanai.

Many thanks for your time and I hope everyone now finds it easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone bumping on this question,

I figured out the fix; thanks to the clue given by @r-beginners.
This is what I want;

```
my_color_scale = [[0.0, '#4c5c73'], [0.1, '#445267'], [0.2, '#3C495C'], [0.3, '#354050'], 
                 [0.4, '#2D3745'], [0.5, '#262D39'], [0.6, '#1E242E'], [0.7, '#161B22'], 
                 [0.8, '#0F1217'], [0.9, '#07090B'], [1.0, '#000000']]
```

I wanted my list of colour with shades/tints and that is essentially what you need to add in your code. 
The `0.0, 0.1, ...., 1.0` next to the Hex Code is used to index your colour and its shades, so later Plotly can use it.

If you use the standard `choropleth` (the other one is `choropleth_mapbox`) in `plotly.express`, this is how you define it. Then just type the variable with the hex codes of your color into the `color_continouos_scale`; e.g. `color_continuous_scale=my_color_scale`.

I found it after re-reading the documentation and asking others in different space about this.

Many thanks for your time!

**Edit 1**: Useful website for Hex Codes: https://color-hex.org/

**Edit 2**: Full code

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

''' PostgreSQL Variables '''
# your postgres login variables

''' PostgreSQL Connection '''
# your postgres connection code

''' SQL Query '''
# your SQL Query 

''' Load SQL Queries into Pandas DataFrame '''
African = pd.DataFrame(SQL_Query_Code,
                       columns=['list-of-all-columns'])

''' Variable for Personal Colours '''
# e.g. HTML/HEx code : '#4c5c73'
# List all of the shades/tints codes; in this example I am using the tints codes
my_color_scale = [[0.0, '#4c5c73'], [0.1, '#5D6C81'], [0.2, '#6F7C8F'], [0.3, '#818C9D'], [0.4, '#939DAB'],
                  [0.5, '#A5ADB9'], [0.6, '#B7BDC7'], [0.7, '#C9CED5'], [0.8, '#DBDEE3'], [0.9, '#EDEEF1'],
                  [1.0, '#FFFFFF']]

''' Plotly graph '''
# Government Respond - School Closing
african_figure1 = px.choropleth(African,
                                locations='countrycode',
                                color='c1_school_closing',
                                color_continuous_scale=my_color_scale,
                                range_color=[0, 3],
                                hover_data={'c1_school_closing': False,
                                            'countrycode': False,
                                            'countryname': False},
                                hover_name='countryname',
                                labels={'c1_school_closing': 'SCALE'})

african_figure1.update_layout(geo_scope='africa',
                              coloraxis_reversescale=True, # To reverse the order of color shades/tints
                              title_text='Government Respond - SCHOOL CLOSING <br> '
                                     'Source: <a href="https://www.bsg.ox.ac.uk/research/research-projects'
                                     '/coronavirus-government-response-tracker#data"> Oxford University '
                                     'CORONAVIRUS '
                                     'Government Respond Tracker</a>')

# african_figure1.show()
# african_figure1.write_html('file/path/file_name.html')
```

The result:

[image: The resulting image]
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Changed to CSS color format based on the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/). All you have to do is specify the colors you want to use in list format.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv",
                   dtype={"fips": str})

import plotly.express as px

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson=counties, locations='fips', color='unemp',
                           color_continuous_scale=["#dc143c", "#ffd700", "#4169e1"],
                           range_color=(0, 12),
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                           zoom=3, center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
                           opacity=0.5,
                           labels={'unemp':'unemployment rate'}
                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for this.
Although, this is not what I am looking for as I am using the standard choropleth not the choropleth_mapbox.

However, it does gives me a clue on how to perform the same task in the standard choropleth.

Many thanks for your time!